# Are rejected suggested edits included in the timeline of a question?

Tags: feature-request, support, timeline

Are rejected suggested edits included in the timeline of a question? It is not easy to find an example to confirm so I just ask a question here.

If it is not included in the timeline, is it possible to include it in the timeline? It may be useful if a rejected edit was actually a good edit and the information can be recovered from the edit, since it is very common for a comprehensive edit by new user to be rejected. It might also provide some useful information for moderation.

Comment: No, rejected suggested edits are not included with any view of a post; not the revisions nor the timeline.

Comment: All suggested edits on a post do show up in the moderator's timeline, whether they are still pending, got approved, got rejected, or just plain got invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the timeline went through a redesign recently and now contains much more features, including suggested edits made on the posts, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277369/timeline):

> [image]